# How to call method in thread time after time?

Tags: android

I have a method that loads data from `Firebase` into `ArrayList`. After this,I use that `ArrayList` to construct `RecyclerView`. I've decided to load data on another thread. Below is my code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_just);

     citiesRecyclerView = 
     (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

     handler = new Handler()
     {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);


            if(msg.what==1)
            {

                cityAdapter = new 
               CityAdapter(MainActivity.this,cities) ;
               citiesRecyclerView.setAdapter(cityAdapter);

            }
        }
    };

     t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         //method that loads data into List.If this method was 
         //successfully done,then I send message 1 to Handler

            loadDataFromFirebase();
        }
    });

    t.start();
   //other operations below 
}
```

Hope,that everything understandable. Code works fine. And my problem is that I need to use `loadDataFromFirebase` method in thread again. I wanted to call `t.start()` again in order to call `loadDataFromFirebase` method,but there was error that `thread already started`. I checked that by writing this code:

```
   if(t.getState()== Thread.State.NEW)
        t.start();
    else
        someMethod();
```

`else` statement worked above.

And my questions are: 
1) Does `loadDataFromFirebase` method  work really on another thread by this way?
2) How to call `loadDataFromFirebase` method again in another thread, if something happened? Do I need to create another variable for `Thread` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to handle all low-level thread work by your own.

Accroding to Android you could:

1. Use AsyncTask (but notice that they have many drawbacks such as context leak in some cases etc),
2. I could suggest you to get into [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) - it's a painless way to use async work in your app.
3. To 'download' data from Firebase you could probably use FCM (push notifications) to load data on demand.

**And what about your question**:
"It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution."(c) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()

Answer (score 1):

If you are using firebase SDK you can use realtime database feature, so do not need to query it each time.

You should just subscribe one time and get updates. For example:

```
firebaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        YourDataObject value = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourDataObject.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

You can read docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/).

Comment: But I read data from specific child each time((( . I don't think that it is possible without querying each time

Comment: You can subscribe for changes to a specific child.

Comment: @andy11 yes, firebase using async callbacks, so don't worry.